# Sum of a faithfully flat module and a flat module

Tags: modules, homological-algebra, projective-module, flatness

For a ring $R$, a left $R$-module $F$ is **flat** if the functor $- \otimes_R F$ brings an exact sequence of right $R$-modules to an exact sequence of right $R$-modules.

It is **faithfully flat** if the functor $- \otimes_R F$ brings a sequence of right $R$-modules to an exact sequence of right $R$-modules if and only if the original sequence is exact.

It is a "standard fact" that the sum of a faithfully flat module and a flat module is faithfully flat. Can someone please explain why this is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tensored sequence splits as two exact sequences, and it suffices to use the exactness of one to recover the exactness of the untensored sequence.

Comment: Yes, of course! Thanks for your help.